# How can I shrink the details section?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

The details section on my report seems to be pegged at 11 inches. I can't shrink it down below that. I can make it larger. Is there somewhere the minimum size for it is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems solved.

I found by selecting a region that extended down below the bottom of the Details section that there were two hidden (invisible until selected) objects that spanned the very bottom of the Details section, the Report Footer section and the Page Footer Section.

Deleting them allowed me to shrink the size of the details section to something more reasonable.

I wasn't the original developer of the report, so perhaps an earlier developer did something wacky or the file got corrupted some how.